# Neo4j large respond tuning

Tags: neo4j

Can anybody help me with the Neo4j 1.9.5 tuning, please?

My query returns ~ 1000 records in the respond. I'm going to paginate the respond with the SKIP ... LIMIT. With LIMIT 100 the respond time is acceptable - 0.5s.

But with LIMIT 106 the performance degrades to 9s. The same degradation I have with SKIP 6 LIMIT 100.

So I've assumed that there should be some setting which might increase LIMIT without performance decreasing.

Comment: please share your data model, your query, environment, setup, memory config etc. Without that no one can give you tuning help

Comment: It is that case when correct clarifying of a question leads to the answer. The problem was fixed on cypher query level. Thanks for the right question.